# Common ways to check for measurability of function?

Tags: measure-theory

Common ways to check for measurability of function?

Or what properties give me measurability? Riemann-integrable?

Particularly,

I'm studying functional analysis and some of the problems require measurability, but I wonder is there some set of "common features for measurability" to check for or some test for measurability?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Yes, the definition, and how the definition behaves with respect to other operations, like composition of functions. But that is the same strategy for any other concept.

Comment: If the function is $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, then you can safely assume that any function wil be measurable unless it isn't for obvious reason.

Comment: The previous comment is pure garbage, of course. Just by checking the definition you can see that it depends on which $\sigma$-algebras of sets are taken in the domain and codomain.

Comment: @user647486 As far as I know, it is quite standard, in the garbage world of Gary Badge, to assume that a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is said to be measurable (without further specification) if preimage of a Borel set is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Somehow the missing details are starting to appear. You are still missing the reason why it is unlikely to step on a non-measurable function when those specific $\sigma$-algebras are chosen.